# Could we stick the "cancel" and "help" links to the top of the "Save Edits" button?

Tags: feature-request, design, comments

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Add comment to a post
- Go to edit it and resize the edit box
- Check the the **cancel** and **help** links positions

**Problem:**

This is what I can see. The **cancel** and **help** links are positioned in the relative height of the edit box which is not much ergonomic. If they were sticked (fixed) to the button, it would be far much better:

[image]

This is what I mean (the link positions are fixed no matter what height has the comment edit box):

[image]

**Environments:**

Google Chrome 67.0.3396.87

Comment: This is a test comment.
Oh, I see the problem now...

Comment: Maybe put the help under [Save Edits], as it is an action that is the contrary of the main button, and put the help at the bottom, because it's not related to the cancel or save edits. Is there a designer on board?

Comment: This is not just when editing post, but when adding a new too.

Comment: You can expand the comment box?!

Comment: @Filnor, you're right there! There's just one of those links.